Uploading a .gif doesn't work on some SE sites
E.g., it doesn't work on http://serverfault.com/, https://askubuntu.com/ and https://superuser.com/questions/ask:



I first noticed the issue ~10h ago on http://serverfault.com/. I use Chrome + Win10.

I  tried to upload this gif (uploading a .gif works on Meta.SE):


Possibly related

500 GB(!) and 5000 objects. What is that? Some Git thing? What is the context?

@This_is_NOT_a_forum https://serverfault.com/a/1157526/126950

A fix was deployed this morning, I've tested a few GIFs and was able to upload successfully, can you try re-uploading the GIF that was causing issues for you?

EDIT: A developer clarified with me that we made some changes to speed up uploading animated GIFs, there are still a few underlying issues that still need to be addressed. Will post another follow-up when ready. Thank you for your patience.

Update from Slate, 17th June -- We've completed the extent of what we have planned here. We've created an explicit limit on image size in megapixels to prevent processing delays while uploading gifs, and failed uploads should now display a more helpful error message.

It worked for me now when testing, in the same speed as uploading ordinary image, and when I tested when bug was reported, it didn't work at all, it's not matter of speeding it up.

@ShadowWizardLoveZelda or FranckDernoncourt (can't @ mention two people in comments) glad to hear that it's working. Could you link me to one of the GIFs you uploaded so I can save it for future testing on our dev environments?

I uploaded the one in the question itself used as example, which failed as the OP said when I tested when bug was first reported. /cc @Franck (you also used this one, or something different?)

@ShadowWizardLoveZelda I used this one

Looks like it's broken in the new upload process which is done internally by Stack Exchange.
Couple of workarounds, until SE add support for gif in the new process:

Upload the gif in a site that still has the imgur upload, e.g. here on Meta Stack Exchange.
Upload the gif on imgur itself then use the link of the image from there.


Thanks, better use option 1 "Upload the gif in a site that still has the imgur upload, e.g. here on Meta Stack Exchange." to reduce likelihood of 404 in the future.

@Franck true, though good chance SE itself will also impose expiration of images at some point when they'll see their storage is getting full. (Pretty sure someone already asked about it in the announcement, and if not - someone need to ask. :))

imho unlikely that SE remove images that were uploaded via SE: only take less than 1TB (considering images including in posts/comments/chat only), and would mess up many posts.  Also, images that were uploaded via SE are CC BY SA licensed, unlike images uploaded directly via imgur without SE.

@Franck sadly, SE is doing many unlikely things lately. (Most as result of AI panic, but still, when they'll need extra money, even those petty bytes of hosting might glitter. The "mess up many posts" is totally not-an-issue for management)
